# Scala: disallow pattern matching that can't be checked for exhaustiveness

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, static-analysis

I would like to allow only those forms of pattern matching in my codebase that can be checked for exhaustiveness. Note that this doesn't mean that I want to disallow non-exhaustive `PartialFunction` literals, because those can be quite useful:

```scala
val foo: List[Option[Int]] = ???
foo.collect {
  case Some(x) => x
}
```

But I want to make sure that I get an error if I ever change `collect` to `map` in the above code, or
if the type of `foo` changes to e. g. `List[Any]` (because then the author couldn't possibly have considered all cases).

Pattern matching on sealed types (traits or classes) is fine, and so is matching primitive types (Int, String etc.). But I don't want to allow non-sealed types (e. g. `Seq`) or type parameters to be matched. E. g. this should be forbidden:

```scala
def f[A](a: A): Int = a match {
  case a: Int => a
  case _ => 42
}
```

Is there a Scala compiler flag or a tool to enforce this? It should be possible to build a check for this using e. g. ScalaFix, but I haven't been able to find an implementation.

Comment: Doesn't the compiler already warn about those? And you can turn that warning into an error so the code doesn't compile.

Comment: No, the Scala compiler does not warn for either of these examples. I do want it to warn for the second example, and I want it to warn for the first example too if I change the type of `foo` to `List[Any]`